# Do you need anything special in a virtual host for search engines

Tags: apache-2.2

I was curious if there are any directives that need to be added in order to allow search engines to catalog the site, or do search engines do this regardless.

Right now I've seen just the basics from [apache's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) web site. nothing about search engines are listed in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing at all. if your website is accessible from the internet - it'll be accessible for the search engines.

one thing you might want to do is to make sure your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file [apache does not come with any by default] does not **prevent** search engines from indexing the content.

you'll obviously need to submit the address of your site to the search engine or at least link it to some site that google / bing / other search angines 'know about' so they can discover your content.

Comment: thank you. I did notice that my web stats show every file being indexed, such a pics and source files.